# Radio Button Updating Database with Last Value Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, radio-button

I am having trouble updating a value in my database for each user with the path that I am currently taking using radio buttons.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>

<% result = 0%>

<h4> <%= user.name  %> </h4>

<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :Quetion_one %>
    <%= f.radio_button :question_one, result = 1 %>
    <%= f.radio_button :question_one, result = 2 %>
    <%= f.radio_button :question_one, result = 3 %>
    <% user.update_attribute(:question_one, result) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am using Paginate, but that is besides the point. I am trying to go through each user and choose a value for a question, either 1, 2, or 3, but unfortunately the way I have it set up, it is only setting the last value (3) into the database for every user. I thought that if I have a result variable and set it to a certain value for each radio button, that the update_attribute would set the value to the chosen one, but it does not. It is possible I do not understand radio buttons fully or I am missing something, but I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should not update inside the view like this.

You should make a form in the view that will send values to a controller action (in this case, `users_controller#create` and/or `users_controller#update`), then you can update the model with the attributes values.

As for the form, this should work (based on the [method's documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button)):

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Question_one %>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 1 %>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 2 %>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 3 %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, I had read about updating in the controller. but I do not fully understand how to use the controller to update, and for this case, my controller for the .erb class has the paginate code residing in it, so I am not able to update a single user in that particular def class. Maybe you have a good resource for me to learn more about updating information in the controller? Sorry, I am brand spanking new in Rails, so a few things are still very confusing.

Comment: I understand. Basically, via an html form, you will "send values" to your controller, that will then decide what to do with them (in your case, update your users). These articles might be good startting points: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/ and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to update user in view itself and this is against the rails convention. You should use update action in controller like (controller#update). And only use submit button in view.

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Quetion_one %>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_one, result = 1 %>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_one, result = 2 %>
  <%= f.radio_button :question_one, result = 3 %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Again if you want to update in view itself, then it will update the user with **result = 0** but it don't update the value set after selecting checkbox because user.update_attributes(:question_one => result) will execute before view render.
so, this will not going to fire the update_attributes method on selecting checkbox.
Hence you have to use submit button and add **update"" action in User controller.

```
def update
 user = User.where(:id => params[:id]).first
 if user && user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  #on sucess
 else
  #on failing to update
 end
end
```